# How to undo dismissing company after you've dismissed them and left the page?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

At the bottom of a company page is a "Dismiss Company" button. (ps: you should really rethink the placement of this button). After I dismiss a company, there is an "Undo" button right away, but what If I've left the page and came back to SO Jobs, how do I undismiss this company?

Answer (score 20):

We currently don't have a way for you to see all the companies you've dismissed. That was a conscious decision because we didn't have a clear use case for it (also, it helped that when we researched what other products were doing, none of them provided a way to undo a dismissal).

However, if you do know the company you want to undismiss, there's a workaround that works:

1. Log out of your account (by doing this, you go back to seeing all the companies / all the jobs)
2. Search the company you want to undismiss
3. Open the company page
4. Log in to your account
5. Go to the bottom of the page, you'll see the link to undo the dismissal of the company.

And regarding the placement... I agree that it's not... amazing, but we have some work planned to redesign the company pages. When that happens, the feature will be easily accessible (as it is right now on the job details page). We just didn't want to wait for the redesign to ship this.

Comment: hmm seems odd - i was expecting to have under my profile under the section of jobs a grid / listbox showing me all companies i've dismissed and allowing me to manage it there...

Comment: Indeed, seems odd. Would this have a chance of getting implemented as a feature request?

Comment: @eis you can definitely ask for it :) if you make a clear case of why it's needed, we aren't opposed to implementing it.

Comment: @g3rv4 Some obvious use cases are: a) Someone doesn't like something about a company, dismisses them, then learns it's changed (e.g. its tech stack, culture/ethics, remote/flex-working policy, etc), b) Someone clicks 'dismiss' by mistake, misses the 'undo', c) Someone misunderstands and doesn't realise 'Dismiss' is permanent (for example maybe they think it's like "skip this company and go to the next one" like in a review queue - which is kinda how it looks from the button being where a 'complete this step' button would be), d) Someone doesn't remember if they dismissed a company months ago