# Allow me to "undismiss" a company

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

From this: [How to undo dismissing company after you've dismissed them and left the page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365620/how-to-undo-dismissing-company-after-youve-dismissed-them-and-left-the-page?cb=1)

You asked for reasons wanting this.  Pretty simple reasons in fact the top ones being:

1. I disliked company Acme because Acme was strictly using go and they didn't have a good vacation policy.  Months later Acme changes to using C# and has a great vacation package.
2. I accidentally dismissed a company and didn't realize leaving the page doesn't allow me to ever see this company again?!?!?
3. I may dismiss a company temporarily for reasons such as what tech stack or perks and then find their management changes to include certain aspects I was looking for and my best friend works there and he lets me know.

I am quite certain that more reasons exist...this is just off the top of my head.

Comment: My cat or my sibling touched the keyboard.

Comment: Lots can change in a company in months or years. If I search now and dismiss a job, then later search for a job in 12 months, the company may have changed drastically (see your first point). Current job search only seems to think about the NOW, not the future

Comment: Lots can change in the jobseeker too, right? Dismiss the company because you're not willing to relocate. Three months later, your partner suddenly gets a great job offer from the exact same city where this company is based...

Comment: Kind of like how I would of wanted to work for Facebook, now I really don't.

Comment: Kind of like how I never wanted to work for Facebook, now I really do.

Comment: You see, Acme is all about loyalty and common values. If Acme is not good enough for you now, then you're never going to be good enough for Acme.

Comment: Research shows that newly unemployed wildly overestimate their employment chances. This implies that they start off with too high a reservation wage, potentially here dismissing companies because of what they perceive to be sub-standard non-pecuniary benefits. Later on, as they realize how their chances actually stand, they'd be willing to actually work for those companies -- but cannot undismiss them. Oh, the horror!

Comment: Or in short: Preferences change.

Answer (score -11):

I think the current functionality is fine. You shouldn't control your jobs information by using dismiss. If you are genuinely interested in jobs, just use the more elaborate search functionality.

Dismiss is there to block companies that disturb your job seeking journey, not as a primary tool to find the right job or as a memory to your jobs preferences.

Use dismiss for: 
a. Companies you will ethically not work for (go against your political persuasions, have personally hurt you, etc...) 
b. Companies too far away. My personal circumstances are that I am extremely unlikely to relocate and therefore, I would not consider jobs in areas away from mine. 
c. Companies that you indend to apply to one day, when you feel ready (high dollar, high tech enterprises) and you won't be just applying on an impromptu basis from some random ad on SE, but you would rather focus fire on them when the time is right

The above are highly unlikely to change. They do sometimes, but it's better to accept that minuscule risk for a superior surfing experience. 
Hence, the dismiss functionality works just right.

It's a case of using the right tool for the job, not augmenting one tool to do a job it's not designed for. In other words: just learn to use dismiss when you truly don't want to hear from them ever again (which is a great use case for me)

Comment: You ignored the use cases the OP provided and then backed your answer up with *your* use cases (which provide no compelling reason not to provide it). If you don't want to undismiss then don't. Undismiss affects none of your use cases listed

Comment: No. I did not ignore his use cases. I said they are invalid. When you look at a screwdriver, you don't ask how can you cut a piece of wood with it. And if someone asks that, you don't automatically assume they have a valid use case. This is a free service offered to millions of users as a "one size fits all" platform. This is not a bespoke niche product with one paying customer who could ask to divide by zero if he pays (true story)

Comment: Your analogies make no sense. Your answer is that the OP doesn't need an undismiss because you don't need it and can't see why he would either. You address none of the use cases he presents. If they are invalid then you need to build a case why that is. You've not done that.

Comment: you are just being argumentative or just in support of needless development. He doesn't need an undismiss as much as he doesn't need an unpay or unsend-email. Just be careful about it. And no, this is not how it works, HE asked for an enhancement, HE needs to prove HE needs it and so far I don't see any need, only unreasonable tweaking that won't make sense on the scale of SE user base.

Comment: The OP did discuss why he feels he needs this. You have discussed why _you_ don't. However, you have not explained why the OP doesn't actually need the feature despite what they've outlined as their reasons for feeling they need it. All you've done is dismissed their opinions, ideas, and arguments with no support and then provided your own as if your own are 1) definitive and facts for the correct procedure (since you're not an SO employee, highly doubting this is the case) 2) not your own opinion, and 3) prove without a doubt that the OP is using the feature wrong.

Comment: I agree with Machavity that this answer really should be edited to actually address the OP's points, not just dismiss them outright. If you disagree this is needed, then that's fine, no need to argue about it. This is _just my opinion._ (Much like your answer is not definitive fact.)

Comment: well... A simple search, something the OP should have done, would reveal that SE staff have already considered this expectation and deemed it unreasonable. It's not a technical difficulty, it's not going to happen because it doesn't make sense from a UI perspective. So, that's a definite fact about how the dismiss was intended to be used. As for my reasoning. I am merely describing the perimeter of the other side of the coin :) I am explaining the use of dismiss, not shooting down the infinite unreasonable use cases "applicable" to this functionality

Comment: If there's already a post that says the SE team _definitely won't_ implement this, I'd argue you should flag this question as a duplicate. I'm not finding a post related to this, other than the one the OP links in the question. In that, they only ask _how_ to do it. Likewise, the staff does _not_ say they won't do this, they only say they, at the time, did not have a use case. (And in the comments, suggest this post with a laid-out use case. Hence the OP asking the question.) If you're thinking of a different post, please, link it and add to the discussion! It might be a topic to revisit.